# How do I estimate the contribution of each kernel in the prediction of the Gaussian Process?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing

Assume that I have a gaussian regression problem, where I have a covariance function K that is estimated based on two kernels K1 and K2. For example K1 is a squared exponential kernel, and K2 is a periodic kernel. How can I know the contribution of each kernel on the prediction of the gaussian process?

The solution to this question  is presented in Figures 5.7 and 5.8 in:

> C. E. Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams, Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, the MIT Press, 2006, ISBN 026218253X. c 2006 Massachusetts Institute of Technology. (free online)

but the authors didn't explain how did they come up with these figures.

This is not a programming question nor a question about the book's specific example. I am interested in learning how do I estimate the influence of each component of the covariance function K on the prediction since it is extremely helpful in the inference, understanding, and interpretation of the gaussian process regression model.

Comment: Since the covariance kernel $k$ is the sum of four kernel $k_i$, the
series $y(x)$ can be regarded as the sum of four independent
unobserved series $y_i(x)$ with kernel $k_i$. A smoothed version
$\widehat{y}_i$ of each component can be computed as a conditional
expectation. My guess is that fig. 5.8 shows contours of 
$\widehat{y}_2(x)$ using the month and the year part of time $x$ as spatial coordinates.

Comment: How do I compute the conditional expectation?

Comment: Use the classical formula for the computational expectation for a
multivariate normal. The vector of the $n$ estimated values for component $i$
is given by $\widehat{\mathbf{y}}_i = \boldsymbol{\mu}_i + \mathbf{K}_i
\mathbf{K}^{-1} [\mathbf{y} - \boldsymbol{\mu}]$. Here the elements $n
\times n$ matrices $\mathbf{K}$ contain the covariance kernel values and
the vectors $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are expectations.

Comment: Oops "computational" expecation is obviously *conditional* expectation. Sorry.

Comment: I tried this method, it will not give the needed results. Because the effect of each kernel will be scaled to the values of the y (see the term $ [y-\mu ] $) and in the book you have covariances that are contributing with small values.

Comment: Use zero vectors for $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_i$, since no trend is used in association with the kernels. I tried this with the estimated hyperparameters given in the book  and got nearly the same results although the time series that I got from the **GPFDA** R package on CRAN is lightly shorter.

Comment: I am currently trying to answer the same question and am making progress. Have a look at the following ticket plus follow the links like the CO2 data of Mauna Loa as given by Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning in chapter 5: https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/491